# ScrollMagic. Add class to two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollmagic

I'm trying to set `visible` class to element `.wordpress` and `.wordpress-txt`

For one element, this work:

```
      var sunScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: 'body',
        triggerHook: 0.5,
        offset: 1000,
        duration: '1000px'
      })
      .setClassToggle(".wordpress", "visible")
      .addTo(controller);
```

For two elements, desn't work (only works second element `.wordpress-txt`):

```
      var sunScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: 'body',
        triggerHook: 0.5,
        offset: 1000,
        duration: '1000px'
      })
      .setClassToggle(".wordpress", "visible")
      .setClassToggle(".wordpress-txt", "visible")
      .addTo(controller);
```

With jQuery selector, doesn't work neither:

```
      var wordpressE = $('.wordpress', '.wordpress-txt')
      var sunScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: 'body',
        triggerHook: 0.5,
        offset: 1000,
        duration: '1000px'
      })
      .setClassToggle(wordpressE, "visible")
      .addTo(controller);
```

How can I add the class to both elements? Thank you in advance

Comment: `.setClassToggle(".wordpress, .wordpress-txt", "visible")` have you tried this?

Comment: `var wordpressE = $('.wordpress', '.wordpress-txt')` surely this would error as the syntax suggests that find `.wordpress` in `.wordpress-txt` element. Instead you can use group selector: `var wordpressE = $('.wordpress, .wordpress-txt')`

Comment: First solution, works. Second, doesn't. Thanks a lot to both ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead you have to pass a group selector in the method:

```
.setClassToggle(".wordpress, .wordpress-txt", "visible")
```